# ListView items appearing too much tall

Tags: android, xml, listview

I'm having a little "graphical" issue with a listview. When the app finishes filling the items, each and everyone of them appear so much tall even if I declared their height and width to wrap_content...
 Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/paperback"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textSize="16sp" 
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="12sp" 
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to remove the outer LinearLayout since it's not doing anything for you here. edit: actually, it's not doing nothing, it might be messing up your layout :-)

Comment: Where is listview in this code?

Comment: @Joris the outer layout is there to contain the background of the entire view. The inner layout is there to contain the listview ;)

Comment: @InnocentKiller the two textviews compose the listview. I'm not populating it statically but dinamically, so I needed the xml to be declared like this

Comment: try setting the height of the outer linear layout to `wrap_content`

Comment: @LeonGuerrero, then problem might be your image that you set in background that is `@drawable/paperback` just try to reduce it's size and check. I am not sure this is the problem but just suggestion though.

Comment: @upenpat already tried. Not working :S

Answer (score 0):

Try this code create a separate list selector xml like list_row.xml and map this title to the list view that you used on your app.. This is my list view code in list view xml.

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@drawable/hline"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_select" />

  Here i mentioned the list selector below



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/list_select"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:padding="3dip" >
 </LinearLayout>



 <LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
 android:layout_width="220dp"
 android:layout_height="40dp"
 android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:padding="3dip" >

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/title"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
     android:text=".."
     android:textAlignment="center"
     android:textColor="#040404"
     android:textSize="12dip"
     android:textStyle="normal"
     android:typeface="sans" />
  </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
```